# How can I replace HttpContext.User in ASP.NET Core after Authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a custom user class `MyPrincipal` with some custom properties, with which I want to replace the authenticated `ClaimsPrincipal`, e.g. `HttpContext.User`

I have added a custom middleware:

```
public class MyMiddleware {
  private readonly RequestDelegate next;

  public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    if (context.User.IsAuthenticated) {
      context.User = new MyPrincipal(context.User);
    }
    await next(context);
  }
}
```

I have registered the middleware to run after authentication, but before MVC in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware()>;
  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

In my `_Layout.cshtml` I want to use a custom property from my `MyPrincipal`:

```
...
@if (User is MyPrincipal) {
  <do stuff>
}
...
```

So far so good, the user is recognized as `MyPrincipal`.

**But when I add a global Authorization policy:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc(options => {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
  });
}
```

Suddenly, the `User` in `_Layout` is just a `ClaimsPrincipal`.

**How can I either stop MVC from replacing my principal, or hook into the pipeline after the authorization policy has completed?**

P.S. I am using the ASP.NET Core 2.0 Preview 2, in case it matters.

Comment: Is something later in the middleware pipeline overwriting your user object?

Comment: @DavidG The only other middleware after mine is MVC; my best guess is it happens in PolicyEvaluator: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PolicyEvaluator` is authenticating the `AuthenticationScheme` which replaces the `Principal`. To fix this remove the `AuthenticationScheme` parameter from the `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` constructor.

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
```

This will apply the policy to all authentication schemes and assumes you have called `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync` elsewhere.

Comment: Great, that did the trick, even if I don't fully understand why :) Btw, what do you mean by "As mentioned in the comments"? Which comments are you referring to?

Comment: You linked the source location where the `PolicyEvaluator` is replacing the `Principal` on the `HttpContext`: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/a4458191c700437a00603116ad92633d1590319d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L33.

Comment: Got it, so if I specify a scheme in the AuthorizationPolicyBuilder, it will do both Authentication and Authorization, while I am only interested in the Authorization bit. Hard to find good documentation on this, thanks again for your answer.